# Meteor js - Undefined var from server side var

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter, callback, client-server

Pretty new to Meteor and actually facing a problem. 
Trying to create a quick page that fetches the most recent twitts of the user. ( server side). In the logs i can see all the tweets being retrieved.

But i'd then like to display them but i just get an undefined var when trying to pass the var from server to client with a callback.

```
//Server Side
 Meteor.methods({checkTwitter: function () {

  var Twit = new TwitMaker({
    consumer_key:         '****', // API key
    consumer_secret:      '****', // API secret
    access_token:         '****', 
    access_token_secret:  '****'
});

  Twit.get('statuses/user_timeline',
    {
        q: 'IngeniousBastar',
        count: 10
    },
    function(err, data, response) {
       var result='test';
       return(data);
    }
);

   }
 });

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Client Side

Meteor.call('checkTwitter', function(err, respJson) {
        if(err) {
          window.alert("Error: " + err.reason);
          console.log("error occured on receiving data on server. ", err );
        } else {
          console.log("respJson: ", respJson);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Are you using this [package](https://github.com/subhog/meteor-twit) ? It seems to be outdated.

Comment: used this one :
https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/twit
But i do manage to get the data from twitter. 

My problem is how to get that data from server to client